# C# webservices maintain session from another webservice

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I have a webshop running which contains parts of cars. The prices next to the parts are loaded from a webservice running else where. This webservice only contains one webmethod: **GetArticleInformation**.

In this webservice there is a link to another webservice **WebshopServiceClient** running elsewhere which contains the info about the cars and holds the prices.

Now when a user select a part of the vehicle he wants to buy the first webservice is called and the method **GetArticleInformation** is executed. In this method I want to create a session which hold the logon of the second webservice ( the database ). In this way I want to prevent that for every call a new logon is required.

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
public GetBackItems GetArticleInformation(User user, Items items) 
{
    //Create session if needed
    client = (WebshopServiceClient)Session["SphinxLogon"];
    if (client == null)
    {
        client = new WebshopServiceClient();
        bool done = client.Logon();

        if (done)
        {
             Session["SphinxLogon"] = client;
        }
    }

    //Get information and send it back
    ...
}
```

Now when the user in the webshop selects a part the session is created but the next time the user selects a part the session is null again.

What am I doing wrong or what am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would consider 'talking' to the various web-services via an internal 'proxy'-procedure -- fired up on app-start for example -- which would handle all traffic etc with the services. That way the individual client sessions do not have to logon or maintain a session with the services but can still be managed via the proxy. Individual clients would get a 'ticket' from the proxy which then could be part of their session and could be used to manage it.

Comment: I am not familair with proxy within webservices. Can you give me an example or link to examples where I can find this? So I can not use the regular Session object to create and hold sessions between 2 webservices?

Comment: ok, sorry if i wasn't clear enough. Here's what I'll do : I'll write up what I mean by a 'proxy'-procedure and how I would use it in a .Net environment and post the link here later today. Tot gauw.

Comment: Here's what I meant : [bare bones 'code' example](http://www.ducis.net/Static/so_webservice.htm)

Comment: Thank you for this tutorial, it works fine in my application! But does the session always stays open? How can I check when a new session is created ( some kind of counter  )...

Comment: You now have one client that is logged in and cached. Every time GetArticles is called that cached client is used for a new web-service request (session ?). You could add a public property (ServiceCalls) to the ServiceProxy class, which is incremented every time GetArticle is called. I have updated the code in the example to show this.

Comment: There is one more problem, 5 min ago the webservice was unavailable. After reuploading the project it works fine again. Could it be that the session was terminated and it blocks the webservice? Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: Heh, I figured this could/would happen, that's why I made SetClient a separate method. So, enclose the actual service call of the client in ServicePoxy in a Try...Catch block. If it fails the exception should give you an idea of what went wrong and you can reset the client to null and call SetClient to renew the connection. If SetClient fails that too will give you an idea of what's up with the WebService. I would have GetArticles return an item-count of for example -1 to signal some error with the WebService to the 'front-end' and log the exceptions from ServicePoxy. See updated example.